# FogBugz - Estimate & EBS

Tags: fogbugz

I have a FogBugz question regarding EBS (Evidence Based Scheduling)...

Developer A estimates Case A at X amount and Developer B ends up taking over Case A before Developer A can get started and before time has been logged against it. If Developer B agrees with the same estimate that Developer A entered, how might we transfer that same estimate to Developer B for the purpose of evidence-based scheduling?

(I want to avoid having Developer B switch the estimate to Y and then back to X)

Comment: You only need to worry about this if it happens for a significant number of cases. If it happens rarely, then it will be an insignificant outlier that the casino algorithm in EBS takes care of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [FogBugz StackExchange question](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/2674/fogbugz-project-planning):

> On (2) - You have hit it, the only workaround right now (aside from writing a plugin that automatically switches the estimator to the current AssignedTo when work begins), is to switch the estimate to Y and then back to X, or have developer B make a minute change to the estimate to make it his own. Sorry, I know that's not ideal. - Brett Kiefer